# Haskell string to list

Tags: haskell

["6","","[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16,17,18],[19,20,21,22,23,24],[25,26,27,28,29,30],[31,32,33,34,35,36]]"]
I must get from this 6 and [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16,17,18],[19,20,21,22,23,24],[25,26,27,28,29,30],[31,32,33,34,35,36]]
I read from file in file it look

6.
[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16,17,18],[19,20,21,22,23,24],[25,26,27,28,29,30],[31,32,33,34,35,36]].

I tried with map and read to convert string but it wasnt working.
sry for english

Comment: You really need to be more specific about what you have tried.  "with map and read" does not tell us that much.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using `map` and `read` directly is, that your list elements don't all have the same types. The first element is (or better: should be converted to) an `Int`, the second an empty list and the third an `` `[[Int]] ``.

To convert the first element of the list into an `Int`, you can say something like `read $ head xs :: Int`, where `xs` is your list of strings.

The second element cannot be directly converted by read, since an empty string will result in an exception (Prelude.read: no parse).

To convert the third element, which is a list of lists of integers, you can simply say something like `read $ xs !! 2 :: [[Int]]`.

This is not safe or elegant, but if your input always has this structure it should work.

Comment: It dont worki with IO string but with string yes. Atm i need conversion from Io to string